# Type argument T extends class doesn't allow class to be used as T parameter in method

Tags: java, netty

So I have this bit of code:

```
public PacketListener packetListener;

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet<?> packet) throws Exception
{
    if (this.channel.isOpen()) {
        try {
            packet.handle(this.packetListener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

on `packet.handle(this.packetListener);` I get the error: `The method handle(capture#1-of ?) in the type Packet<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (PacketListener)`. What is wrong with this? I mean I know that the ? type is unknown and it usually disallows parameters of any type (or at least so I've read), but in the code the type argument extends `PacketListener` so I don't see the error.

The Packet class looks like this:

```
public interface Packet<T extends PacketListener>
{
    void encode(PacketDataSerializer packetdataserializer) throws IOException;

    void decode(PacketDataSerializer packetdataserializer) throws IOException;

    void handle (T listener);
}
```

And before assuming anything, no it's not Minecraft Server related, yes I helped myself with the naming and structure from the Minecraft Server source code (the one from bukkit/spigot servers).

EDIT:

Alright a comment got me thinking so I tested something and it's not a wildcard and it doesn't work...

```
private static <T extends PacketListener> void a(Packet<T> packet, PacketListener packetlistener) {
    packet.handle(packetlistener);
}
```

Comment: Try `Packet<? super PacketListener>`

Comment: It works but why can't I just leave the ? alone. I mean it's for sure something that extends PacketListener...

Comment: The short version has to do with covariance, contravariance, and the fact that the wildcard type in java (`<?>`) is covariant. You can assign a `?` to the upper bound, but you can't assign the upper bound to `?`. [This SO post has a couple of good top answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), but in general you're not going to be able to pass a class-level generic parameter to a wildcard type.

Comment: @Rogue I edited my question with a different trial of a solution

Comment: Well, it's essentially the same problem. `T extends PacketListener` is a covariant bound, and you need a contravariant one. That or just a nonvariant `Packet<PacketListener>`, and I could also remind you that you can pass a subclass of `PacketListener` to a method parameter which is just `PacketListener` (no generics).

Comment: Alright, thanks, I just wanted to know why minecraft does it like that, now i'll find a convenient workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at this code:

```java
private static <T extends PacketListener> void a(Packet<T> packet,
                                                 PacketListener packetlistener) {
    packet.handle(packetlistener);
}
```

This calls the `handle` method on the `packet` object, which has type `Packet<T>`. This method's signature is defined in the `Packet` interface as:

```java
    void handle (T listener);
```

So it accepts a parameter of type `T`. But you are calling it with the argument `packetlistener`, which has type `PacketListener`. That is, the argument's type is not `T`, because in general `T` can be some subtype of `PacketListener`, but you only provided the base type `PacketListener`.

The simplest fix is to require the `packetlistener` object to have the type `T`, so it can be accepted by the `handle` method:

```java
private static <T extends PacketListener> void a(Packet<T> packet,
                           /* changed here -> */ T packetlistener) {
    packet.handle(packetlistener);
}
```

Comment: Welp. Minecraft Servers are working weirdly, anyhow, I removed type parameters in general 'cuz I never actually wanted them, so I only added `<T extends PacketListener> void handle (T listener);`